# Comments in sed command file

Tags: linux, sed, gnu, gnu-sed

Can I put comments (or something functionally equivalent) into a sed command file?

`subs.sed`

```
s/this/that/g
# comment
s/it/they/g
```

```
$ sed -i -f subs.sed <(echo this it)
that they
```

Comment: That is a valid comment in sed syntax. What verrsion/OS are you using?

Comment: @0stone0 I just hadn't tried that yet... I've never seen and been unable to find a sed command file syntax reference

Comment: So your actually question is *"Can I use comments in my sed file?"*: Yes ;)

Comment: @0stone0 I guess. I didn't know there were comments in sed in the first place, nor any idea what their syntax might be. You can post the answer if you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, comments can be added to a sed file using `#`.

---

From the manual page of [`sed`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sed):

> ###### Command Synopsis
>
> ...
>
> ```
> #comment
> ```
>
> The comment extends until the next newline (or the end of a -e script fragment).